# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'x Module' before initialization

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

The application was working just fine until I upgraded @angular-builders/custom-webpack to v12 to match with @angular/core v12.  If I change the version of @angular-builders/custom-webpack back to v9, there is no error.
Does anyone familiar with this issue? If it's circular dependency issue, what modules are being dependent on each other should be shown in the console.

below is my webpack.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        util: false,
        os: false,
        crypto: false,
        stream: false,
        fs: false
      }
    },
  };
```

[Click here to see the screenshot of error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZX6w.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.